# PowerBI direct query connection to PostgreSQL error. OLE or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We couldn't fold the expression to the data source

Tags: postgresql, odbc, powerbi

According to information from [Microsoft DataConnectors](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/docs/odbc.md) I want to create a connector from PowerBi to PostgreSQL via [this ODBC driver](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) using **direct query**. I reused the code from the [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/tree/master/samples/ODBC/SqlODBC), just adjusted the ConnectionString, nothing else.
After building a .mez file that I imported to the PowerBI, I want to connect to the PostgreSQL server. 
[This is how the connection dialog looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3T8y.png). The connection is successful and I can see the tables in DB and use them. And now, here is where the issue comes in: When I select some column to display the data in table or plot, I get [OLE or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We couldn't fold the expression to the data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHt3U.png). I Also enabled tracing in Diagnostic options, so here is the log content:

```
DataMashup.TraceWarning: 24579:
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6199845Z",
    "Action": "OdbcQuery/FoldingWarning",
    "HostProcessId": "25020",
    "Function Name": "Group",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "f06a4b5b-09ba-40ce-bd99-424710286b77",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 1,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000051"
DataMashup.TraceInformation: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6199552Z",
    "Action": "BackgroundThread/RollingTraceWriter/Flush",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 8,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000560"
DataMashup.TraceWarning: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6199999Z",
    "Action": "OdbcQuery/FoldingWarning",
    "HostProcessId": "25020",
    "ErrorMessage": "This ODBC driver doesn't set the GroupByCapabilities feature. You can override it by using SqlCapabilities.",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "f06a4b5b-09ba-40ce-bd99-424710286b77",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 1,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000159"
DataMashup.TraceInformation: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6200385Z",
    "Action": "BackgroundThread/RollingTraceWriter/Flush",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 9,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000215"
DataMashup.TraceWarning: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6201305Z",
    "Action": "OdbcQueryDomain/ReportFoldingFailure",
    "HostProcessId": "25020",
    "Exception": "Exception:\r\nExceptionType: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.FoldingFailureException, Microsoft.MashupEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nMessage: Folding failed. Please take a look the information in the trace.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Odbc.OdbcQuery.Group(Grouping grouping)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "f06a4b5b-09ba-40ce-bd99-424710286b77",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 1,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000504"
DataMashup.TraceInformation: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6202107Z",
    "Action": "BackgroundThread/RollingTraceWriter/Flush",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 8,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0000154"
DataMashup.TraceWarning: 24579: 
    "Start": "2018-05-18T10:51:56.6199413Z",
    "Action": "RemotePageReader/RunStub",
    "HostProcessId": "25020",
    "Exception": "Exception:\r\nExceptionType: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ValueException, Microsoft.MashupEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nMessage: [Expression.Error] We couldn't fold the expression to the data source. Please try a simpler expression.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Odbc.OdbcQueryDomain.ReportFoldingFailure(NotSupportedException ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query, Func`2 operation)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.VisitQuery(Query query)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptimizingQueryVisitor.Optimize(Query query)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.Query.QueryTableValue.get_OptimizedQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.Query.QueryTableValue.GetReader()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.Interface.Tracing.TracingDataReaderSource.get_PageReader()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.c__DisplayClass11.c__DisplayClass13.b__10()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePageReader.c__DisplayClass7.b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "ProductVersion": "2.58.5103.501 (PBIDesktop)",
    "ActivityId": "f06a4b5b-09ba-40ce-bd99-424710286b77",
    "Process": "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40",
    "Pid": 11080,
    "Tid": 1,
    "Duration": "00:00:00.0005557"
```

Any ideas how to resolve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just connected to PostgreSQL with a Direct Query storage mode for the first time today, and ran into this error as well. Like you, the connection and everything else seemed to work fine, but then threw an error when trying to use visuals that worked fine when using the Import storage mode.

My error read: `OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We couldn't fold the expression to the data source. Please try a simpler expression.` I assume that the last sentence was added in a later version of Power BI.

Carl de Souza explains Query Folding [here](https://carldesouza.com/query-folding-in-power-bi/) and it appears that Direct Querying attempts to fold as much of the analysis into the Native Query as possible. I hadn't specified any query when I first pulled in the data, but once I did the error disappeared.

For any who don't know how to do this, after clicking 'Get Data' (or 'New Source' if already in the Query Editor) and choosing PostreSQL database, make sure to add a SQL statement in the Advanced options section.

For me, a simple 
     `SELECT * FROM my_schema."my_table_name"` 
was sufficient.

"[Sample filling out of the PostgreSQL database popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsmru.png)